# Batman's Rule: Is it thrown out the window in the new DC Universe?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

So, some stick-in-the-mud dredged up this question:

[Did Batman break his one rule?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/did-batman-break-his-one-rule)

It got me thinking about the [*Batman Vs Superman: Dawn of Justice* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/) movie, which (presumably) is going to set in motion DC's version of the MCU since it involves a few new players who will have their own origin movies hitting theaters soon.  And in *B v S*, there's a scene where Batman goes into a warehouse and essentially kills everyone in it.  He's throwing bombs, he's throwing grenades, he's breaking people's necks, etc...

So, historically Batman has had his "No Kill" rule.  Which, some theorize, is actually a "No Murder" rule.  But, this is clearly premeditated murder, because he came armed to the teeth and knew people were going to die.  And I'm curious if anyone knows how that's justified in Batman's ethos, or if Batman in this new DCEU (DC Extended Universe) is going to not necessarily live by this rule.

Comment: Related: [Wasn't the Dark Knight against killing criminals?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50981/49). It might even be an exact duplicate of that question if you're really just asking how it's justified in the DCEU. If you're asking a more general question, though, you might want to point that out.

Comment: Related a bit : [Why does Batman brand criminals?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/why-does-batman-brand-criminals)